# Mirroring a repository with changes applied to each branch

Tags: git

I have a repository which is a fork of another. (Not in the GitHub sense; the repositories are not linked this way.) I continue development in the `master` branch, but for convenience I mirror the upstream project's branches with an `upstream/` prefix, like this:

```
git remote add upstream ...
git fetch --prune upstream
git push --prune origin \
    '+refs/remotes/upstream/*:refs/heads/upstream/*' \
    '+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/upstream/*'
```

This works pretty well.

I have since added configuration files for a continuous integration service. But since these configuration files are not in the `upstream/` branches, CI doesn't trigger when changes are pushed to these branches.

Would it make sense to change my mirroring script to add the configuration files to every `upstream/` branch? How would I best achieve this?

Ideally, I would like to do this in such a way that it is easy to pull changes from `upstream/master` to `master`. I think if I simply add a commit on top of each branch, it would get in the way of doing so.